# Convert returned JSON Object Properties to (lower first) camelCase

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, lodash, underscore.js

I have JSON returned from an API like so:

```
Contacts: [{ GivenName: "Matt", FamilyName: "Berry" }]
```

To keep this consistent with my code style (camelCase - lower case first letter) I want to transform the array to produce the following:

```
 contacts: [{ givenName: "Matt", familyName: "Berry" }]
```

What's the easiest/best way to do this? Create a new Contact object and iterate over all the contacts in the returned array?

```
var jsonContacts = json["Contacts"],
    contacts= [];
        
_.each(jsonContacts , function(item){
    var contact = new Contact( item.GivenName, item.FamilyName );
    contacts.push(contact);
});
```

or can I map the original array or transform it somehow?

Comment: If you are really burned to use the camelcase notation in your javascript you are going to have to map the incoming objects. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/ should help you with with mapping.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Here's a reliable, recursive function that will properly camelCase all of a JavaScript object's properties:

```
function toCamel(o) {
  var newO, origKey, newKey, value
  if (o instanceof Array) {
    return o.map(function(value) {
        if (typeof value === "object") {
          value = toCamel(value)
        }
        return value
    })
  } else {
    newO = {}
    for (origKey in o) {
      if (o.hasOwnProperty(origKey)) {
        newKey = (origKey.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + origKey.slice(1) || origKey).toString()
        value = o[origKey]
        if (value instanceof Array || (value !== null && value.constructor === Object)) {
          value = toCamel(value)
        }
        newO[newKey] = value
      }
    }
  }
  return newO
}
```

Test:

```
var obj = {
  'FirstName': 'John',
  'LastName': 'Smith',
  'BirthDate': new Date(),
  'ArrayTest': ['one', 'TWO', 3],
  'ThisKey': {
    'This-Sub-Key': 42
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(toCamel(obj)))
```

Output:

```
{
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Smith",
    "birthDate":"2017-02-13T19:02:09.708Z",
    "arrayTest": [
        "one", 
        "TWO", 
        3
    ],
    "thisKey":{
        "this-Sub-Key":42
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest checking for `o.hasOwnProperty(key)` and changing `if (typeof value === "object")` to `if (value !== null && typeof value === "object")`. Without the check for `value !== null` this function converts nulls to empty objects.

Comment: Good tips - will add those in.

Comment: This will loose value information if o is Date object (or any Object which does not have own property).
Checkout demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPqZLY?editors=1010

Comment: A year later, I finally took the time to properly detect non-plain-object properties (like `Date`). We check that the constructor is an `Object` before camel-casing the rest of it.

Comment: @brandonscript, can you help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425537/lowercase-json-keys-to-camelcase ?

Comment: Woa, why did it camel-case the value for 'thisKey' as well... ? Surely the OP, or anybody, would not want the data changed as well. Just the property names?

Comment: What are you talking about? Please provide an example. Here is what I think you mean: https://jsfiddle.net/41zeshe2/.

Comment: @brandonscript You also need to check if the value of the property on the object is an array, and call it recursively then, too.

Comment: Yep, it does that. First if statement.

Comment: @brandonscript It actually misses if any properties are an array, yours only checks if the main object is an array.  


This line is missing a check to see if it's an array:   

`if (value !== null && value.constructor === Object)`


Here's an example of yours failing:  
 https://plnkr.co/edit/tEBYU3pQmJJZyl84CFo5  


With the fix of checking for an array: https://plnkr.co/edit/78gDwcLChAOT31XGoLG6

Comment: Good catch @Justin. Want to edit the answer? I’ll approve.

Comment: There is missing ` if (!isNaN(parseInt(origKey))) {` in array for - in other case it will also take 'extension methods' from TypeScript 
 @brandonscript

Comment: Not sure what you’re trying to suggest. Why would you want to search for a string key converted to an int?

Comment: No, i dont want to - just 
`if (o instanceof Array) {
    newO = []
    for (origKey in o) {` is returning too much results - which are functions.

Comment: Can you provide an example in a jsfiddle? I'll update the answer.

Comment: Sure, https://jsfiddle.net/9bdnc4fv/1/
look at that null
`{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","birthDate":"2018-02-08T20:01:58.044Z","arrayTest":["one","TWO",3,null],"thisKey":{"this-Sub-Key":42}}`

@edit - updated with ToCamelCase

Comment: OHH now I see what you're saying. I shouldn't have used `for (key in arr)` to iterate an array in the first place. Switching it to `forEach()` prevents this from happening. Or, even `.map()` will make it shorter.

Comment: I'd rather use the regex `/([A-Z]+)(.*)/` instead of blindly replacing the first char, it will also match something like DOB or URL (which would result in dOB with this solution)

Comment: @Mordechai regex parsing an object can be very dangerous. Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 128):

If you would use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) instead of underscore, this would do:

```
_.mapKeys(obj, (v, k) => _.camelCase(k))
```

This would convert both `TitleCase` and `snake_case` to `camelCase`. Note that it is not recursive though.

Comment: Note: This does not work on nested properties, only top-level keys.

Answer (score 60):

You can do this with this recursive function (with lodash and ES6):

```
import { camelCase } from 'lodash';

const camelizeKeys = (obj) => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.map(v => camelizeKeys(v));
  } else if (obj != null && obj.constructor === Object) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(
      (result, key) => ({
        ...result,
        [camelCase(key)]: camelizeKeys(obj[key]),
      }),
      {},
    );
  }
  return obj;
};
```

Test:

```
const obj = {
  'FirstName': 'John',
  'LastName': 'Smith',
  'BirthDate': new Date(),
  'ArrayTest': ['one', 'TWO', 3],
  'ThisKey': {
    'This-Sub-Key': 42
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(camelizeKeys(obj)))
```

Output:

```
{  
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Smith",
   "birthDate": "2018-05-31T09:03:57.844Z",
   "arrayTest":[  
      "one",
      "TWO",
      3
   ],
   "thisKey":{  
      "thisSubKey": 42
   }
}
```

Comment: Exactly as I needed. Thanks.

Comment: thanks a lot. works fine. I would be replace 
`obj !== null && obj.constructor === Object`
with  `_.isPlainObject(obj)`

Comment: Perfectly converts a nested object (including arrays and whatnot), which can't be said about some of the other answers here. +1

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that actually works for all cases

Comment: this should be the accepted answer - most up to date

Answer (score 25):

To change a plain object's keys from `snake_case` to `camelCase` ***recursively*** try the following
(which uses [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/master#camelCase)):

```
function objectKeysToCamelCase(snake_case_object) {
  var camelCaseObject = {};
  _.forEach(
    snake_case_object,
    function(value, key) {
      if (_.isPlainObject(value) || _.isArray(value)) {     // checks that a value is a plain object or an array - for recursive key conversion
        value = objectKeysToCamelCase(value);               // recursively update keys of any values that are also objects
      }
      camelCaseObject[_.camelCase(key)] = value;
    }
  )
  return camelCaseObject;
};
```

test in this [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/jtsRo9yU12geH7fkQ0WL?p=preview)

**Note**: also works recursively for objects within arrays

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for well-known JSON objects which could contain objects or arrays.

Comment: @Kody by "well-known JSON objects" do you mean something like `{ "name_of": {"name_of_of":"John"}, "age_of":[{"array_object":"John"},40,50], "car_type":null }` as [defined here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) - it works fine for JSON objects & nested JSON objects - PLUNKER updated - but not for converting keys of objects (JSON or otherwise) inside arrays - due to the `_.isPlainObject(value)` check.

Comment: @Kody - code & plunker updated just for you - now works with objects (JSON or otherwise) nested inside arrays :-)

Comment: plunker really saved my lot of time.

Comment: I changed _.isPlainObject(value) to _.isObject(value) and it worked for me, thanks!

Comment: took the liberty of publishing this to npm as a https://www.npmjs.com/package/camel-case-props

Comment: Notice That This flattens an array if you pass to it - and returns an object instead

Comment: As @GalBracha said, this doesn't appear to keep arrays as arrays. I hacked this together instead: https://plnkr.co/edit/OnLVNqq7dHW1T3ukuyd1

Comment: @ropeladder (and GalBracha) - well sleuthed - but note that the question specifically asks to convert JSON object properties - not array values - hence the solution is to accept / convert / return an object.

Answer (score 16):

Using lodash and ES6, this will replace all keys recursively to camelcase:

```
const camelCaseKeys = (obj) => {
  if (!_.isObject(obj)) {
    return obj;
  } else if (_.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.map((v) => camelCaseKeys(v));
  }
  return _.reduce(obj, (r, v, k) => {
    return { 
      ...r, 
      [_.camelCase(k)]: camelCaseKeys(v) 
    };
  }, {});
};
```

Comment: my favorite solution

Comment: This will fail if we have objects like this: [{ hello: 0 }, { hello: null }, { hello: undefined }, { hello: false }] it will return [{hello: {}}, {hello: {}}, {hello: {}), {hello: {}}]

Can be fixed by adding 

if (obj === 0 || obj === null || obj === undefined || obj === false) { return obj; }

Comment: Good catch the shorthand version was inconsistent with the expanded version. I've updated to show only expanded answer

Answer (score 10):

Just use humps

```
humps.camelize('hello_world');
humps.camelizeKeys(object, options); // will work through entire object
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/humps

Comment: Great library rec.

Answer (score 6):

This is a great use case for [axios interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)

Basically, define a client class and attach a before/after interceptor that converts the request/response data.

```
export default class Client {
    get(url, data, successCB, catchCB) {
        return this._perform('get', url, data, successCB, catchCB);
    }

    post(url, data, successCB, catchCB) {
        return this._perform('post', url, data, successCB, catchCB);
    }

    _perform(method, url, data, successCB, catchCB) {
        // https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors
        // Add a response interceptor
        axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
            response.data = toCamelCase(response.data);
            return response;
        }, (error) => {
            error.data = toCamelCase(error.data);
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });

        // Add a request interceptor
        axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
            config.data = toSnakeCase(config.data);
            return config;
        }, (error) => {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });

        return axios({
            method: method,
            url: API_URL + url,
            data: data,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        }).then(successCB).catch(catchCB)
    }
}
```

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/daino3/3da80fe2a3c8f9411214044a7f5611b3) with a longer example using React/axios.

Comment: IMO - this may be the best answer, using an interceptor is a very clean way to move all snake_case keys into camelCase and keep the code in a single sane place, tyvm

Answer (score 5):

there's a nice npm module for this..
https://www.npmjs.com/package/camelcase-keys

```
npm install camelcase-keys
```

```
const camelcaseKeys = require( "camelcase-keys" );

camelcaseKeys( { Contacts: [ { GivenName: "Matt", FamilyName: "Berry" } ] }, { deep: true } );
```

will return...

```
{ contacts: [ { givenName: "Matt", familyName: "Berry" } ] }
```

Comment: I particularly love this answer as the whole package is ~ 9kb. Works nicely for me within the react framework, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

This solution based on the plain js solution above, **uses [loadash](https://lodash.com/docs/#camelCase)** and **Keeps an array if passed as a parameter** and Only change the **Keys**

```js
function camelCaseObject(o) {
    let newO, origKey, value
    if (o instanceof Array) {
        newO = []
        for (origKey in o) {
            value = o[origKey]
            if (typeof value === 'object') {
                value = camelCaseObject(value)
            }
            newO.push(value)
        }
    } else {
        newO = {}
        for (origKey in o) {
            if (o.hasOwnProperty(origKey)) {
                newO[_.camelCase(origKey)] = o[origKey]
            }
        }
    }
    return newO
}

// Example
const obj = [
{'my_key': 'value'},
 {'Another_Key':'anotherValue'},
 {'array_key':
   [{'me_too':2}]
  }
]
console.log(camelCaseObject(obj))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: The function is only recursive in dealing with Arrays. Once it hits a non-Array object, it only camel-cases the top level of property keys.

Comment: This is not pure JS solution. This requires lodash so technically it's not pure JS...

Answer (score 3):

Well I took up the challenge and think I figured it out:

```
var firstToLower = function(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + str.slice(1);
};

var firstToUpper = function(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
};

var mapToJsObject = function(o) {
    var r = {};
    $.map(o, function(item, index) {
        r[firstToLower(index)] = o[index];
    });
    return r;
};

var mapFromJsObject = function(o) {
    var r = {};
    $.map(o, function(item, index) {
        r[firstToUpper(index)] = o[index];
    });
    return r;
};


// Map to
var contacts = [
    {
        GivenName: "Matt",
        FamilyName: "Berry"
    },
    {
        GivenName: "Josh",
        FamilyName: "Berry"
    },
    {
        GivenName: "Thomas",
        FamilyName: "Berry"
    }
];

var mappedContacts = [];

$.map(contacts, function(item) {
    var m = mapToJsObject(item);
    mappedContacts.push(m);
});

alert(mappedContacts[0].givenName);


// Map from
var unmappedContacts = [];

$.map(mappedContacts, function(item) {
    var m = mapFromJsObject(item);
    unmappedContacts.push(m);
});

alert(unmappedContacts[0].GivenName);
```

[Property converter (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/HSASK/3/)

The trick is handling the objects as arrays of object properties.

Comment: thats a nice solution!  Both the alerts come out uppercase but I get the jist.   The whole thing is bugging me, it messes up all my models/controllers if I do and if I dont change it.  Its just a pain.  Thanks.

Comment: it's the property name that is now in camelcase notice the `.givenName` in map to and `.GivenName` in map from... It's confirmation that the property has changed name and not the value.

Comment: It's a design decision, it's the hard part of having a dynamic language. Apply certain conventions to yourself to keep everything in track :)

Answer (score 3):

Using lodash, you can do it like this:

```
export const toCamelCase = obj => {
  return _.reduce(obj, (result, value, key) => {
    const finalValue = _.isPlainObject(value) || _.isArray(value) ? toCamelCase(value) : value;
    return { ...result, [_.camelCase(key)]: finalValue };
  }, {});
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's handy library you might wanna try:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/camelize2

You simply need to install it with `npm install --save camelize2` and then

```
const camelize = require('camelize2')

const response = {
   Contacts: [{ GivenName: "Matt", FamilyName:"Berry" }]
}

const camelizedResponse = camelize(response)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution similar to @brandonscript, but in more ES6-functional way:

```js
const camelCaseString = str => (
  (str.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + str.slice(1) || str).toString() 
);

const objectToCamelCase = val => {
  if (typeof val != 'object' || val === null) {
    return val;
  }
 
  if (val instanceof Array) {
    return val.map(objectToCamelCase);
  }
 
  return Object.keys(val)
    .filter(prop => val.hasOwnProperty(prop))
    .map(prop => ({[camelCaseString(prop)]: objectToCamelCase(val[prop])}))
    .reduce((prev, current) => ({...prev, ...current}))
};

// Example:
let converted = objectToCamelCase({UserId: 1, Hobbies: [{Id: 1, Label: "Read"}], Name: "John Doe"});

console.log(converted)
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed a generic method that accepted an array or object. This is what I'm using (I borrowed KyorCode's `firstToLower()` implementation):

```js
function convertKeysToCamelCase(obj) {
    if (!obj || typeof obj !== "object") return null;

    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        return $.map(obj, function(value) {
            return convertKeysToCamelCase(value);
        });
    }

    var newObj = {};
    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
        key = key.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + key.slice(1);
        if (typeof value == "object" && !(value instanceof Array)) {
          value = convertKeysToCamelCase(value);
        }
        newObj[key] = value;
    });

    return newObj;
};
```

Example calls:

```js
var contact = { GivenName: "Matt", FamilyName:"Berry" };

console.log(convertKeysToCamelCase(contact));
// logs: Object { givenName="Matt", familyName="Berry"}

console.log(convertKeysToCamelCase([contact]));
// logs: [Object { givenName="Matt", familyName="Berry"}]

console.log(convertKeysToCamelCase("string"));
// logs: null

console.log(contact);
// logs: Object { GivenName="Matt", FamilyName="Berry"}
```

Comment: inside of the `$.each` loop, you should add `if (value instanceof Array) {value = convertKeysToCamelCase(value);}`
to ensure that values that are Arrays can also be mapped

Comment: Good point. Arrays work but non-array objects do not. I edited to support those.

Answer (score 1):

Took the challenge with lodash and some es6+ features
Here is my implementation with the reduce function.

```
function deeplyToCamelCase(obj) {
  return _.reduce(obj, (camelCaseObj, value, key) => {
    const convertedDeepValue = _.isPlainObject(value) || _.isArray(value)
      ? deeplyToCamelCase(value)
      : value;
    return { ...camelCaseObj, [_.camelCase(key)] : convertedDeepValue };
  }, {});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lodash ...

```js
function isPrimitive (variable) {
  return Object(variable) !== variable
}

function toCamel (variable) {
  if (isPrimitive(variable)) {
    return variable
  }

  if (_.isArray(variable)) {
    return variable.map(el => toCamel(el))
  }

  const newObj = {}
  _.forOwn(variable, (value, key) => newObj[_.camelCase(key)] = toCamel(value))

  return newObj
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this simply by using `json-case-convertor`

```
const jcc = require('json-case-convertor')
const jsonData = ''//you json data to convert
const camelCasedJson = jcc.camelCaseKeys(jsonData) //Convert all the keys of object to snake case
```

This will handle all cascaded object as well

Answer (score 1):

This function loop recursively through the object keys and using `lodash` returns a new object with every field converted to `camelCase`. It works also with arrays, nested arrays, nested objects.

```
function deepCamelCase (obj) {
  const c = {}

  if (typeof obj !== 'object') return obj

  _.mapKeys(obj, (v, k) => {
    let w = {}
  
    if (typeof v === 'object') {
      if (Array.isArray(v)) {
        const k = []
        for (const i of v) {
          k.push(deepCamelCase(i))
        }
      } else {
        _.mapValues(v, (n, m) => {
          if (Array.isArray(n)) {
            const k = []
            for (const i of n) {
              k.push(deepCamelCase(i))
            }
            w[_.camelCase(m)] = k
          } else {
            w[_.camelCase(m)] = deepCamelCase(n)
          }
        })
      }
    } else {
      w = v
    }
  
    c[_.camelCase(k)] = w
  })
  return c
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated code using the reference from https://plnkr.co/edit/jtsRo9yU12geH7fkQ0WL?p=preview
This handles the Objects with array with objects inside it too and so on, by keeping arrays as arrays (which you can iterate over using map)

```
function snakeToCamelCase(snake_case_object){
  var camelCaseObject;
  if (isPlainObject(snake_case_object)) {        
    camelCaseObject = {};
  }else if(isArray(snake_case_object)){
    camelCaseObject = [];
  }
  forEach(
    snake_case_object,
    function(value, key) {
      if (isPlainObject(value) || isArray(value)) {
        value = snakeToCamelCase(value);
      }
      if (isPlainObject(camelCaseObject)) {        
        camelCaseObject[camelCase(key)] = value;
      }else if(isArray(camelCaseObject)){
        camelCaseObject.push(value);
      }
    }
  )
  return camelCaseObject;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my take; more readable and with less nesting than brandoncode's implementation, and with more room for handling edge cases like `Date` (which isn't handled, by the way) or `null`:

```
function convertPropertiesToCamelCase(instance) {
    if (instance instanceof Array) {
        var result = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < instance.length; i++) {
            result[i] = convertPropertiesToCamelCase(instance[i]);
        }

        return result;
    }

    if (typeof instance != 'object') {
        return instance;
    }

    var result = {};

    for (var key in instance) {
        if (!instance.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            continue;
        }

        result[key.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + key.substring(1)] = convertPropertiesToCamelCase(instance[key]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but when translated to TypeScript, this drops properties defined with getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

Building on goredwards answer (which didn't handle the array fields correctly)

```
function objectKeysToCamelCase(snake_case_object) {
  let camelCaseObject = {}
  _.forEach(
    snake_case_object,
    function(value, key) {
      if (_.isPlainObject(value)) {
        value = objectKeysToCamelCase(value)
      } else if (_.isArray(value)) {
        value = value.map(v => _.isPlainObject(v) ? objectKeysToCamelCase(v) : v)
      }
      camelCaseObject[_.camelCase(key)] = value
    },
  )
  return camelCaseObject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is code I found for it, not fully tested though, but worth sharing.
It is far more readable than other answers, not sure about performance.

test it http://jsfiddle.net/ms734bqn/1/

```
const toCamel = (s) => {
      return s.replace(/([-_][a-z])/ig, ($1) => {
        return $1.toUpperCase()
          .replace('-', '')
          .replace('_', '');
      });
    };

const isArray = function (a) {
  return Array.isArray(a);
};

const isObject = function (o) {
  return o === Object(o) && !isArray(o) && typeof o !== 'function';
};

const keysToCamel = function (o) {
  if (isObject(o)) {
    const n = {};

    Object.keys(o)
      .forEach((k) => {
        n[toCamel(k)] = keysToCamel(o[k]);
      });

    return n;
  } else if (isArray(o)) {
    return o.map((i) => {
      return keysToCamel(i);
    });
  }

  return o;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript, shoud work fine

```
function convertKeysToCamelCase(object) {
    if(object === undefined || object === null || typeof object !== "object") {
        return object;
    } else {
        if(Array.isArray(object)) {
            return object.map(item => convertKeysToCamelCase(item));
        } else {
            return Object.entries(object).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
                result[key.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + key.slice(1)] = convertKeysToCamelCase(value);
                return result;
            }, {});
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Datawaeve Script to Convert Nested JSON Keys into Camcel Case

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Objects
import * from dw::core::Strings
fun toCamelCase(str: String) = camelize(str)
fun convertKeys(obj: Any): Any =
    obj match {
    case is Object -> 
            obj mapObject ((value, key) -> 
                {
        (toCamelCase(key)): convertKeys(value)
    }
            )
        case is Array ->
            obj map convertKeys($)
        else -> obj
}
---
convertKeys(payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for camelCase to Pascalcase. My object is camelCase and need to convert it to Pascalcase based on the C# class property name.

Here I have modified the method,

```
var toPascalCase = function (Object) {
    var NewObject, origKey, newKey, value
    if (Object instanceof Array) {
        return Object.map(function (value) {
            if (typeof value === "object") {
                value = toPascalCase(value)
            }
            return value
        })
    } else {
        NewObject = {}
        for (origKey in Object) {
            if (Object.hasOwnProperty(origKey)) {
                newKey = (origKey.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + origKey.slice(1) || origKey).toString()
                value = Object[origKey]
                if (value instanceof Array || (value !== null && value.constructor === Object)) {
                    value = toPascalCase(value)
                }
                NewObject[newKey] = value
            }
        }
    }
    return NewObject
}
```

**Get Output:**

```
console.log(result);
result = toPascalCase(result);
console.log(result);
```

Here result is my object.

**Before Conversion:**

```
{
    "id": 187,
    "fromUserId": 1,
    "fromUserFullName": "Super Admin",
    "toUserId": 3,
    "toUserFullName": "Super Admin",
    "message": "Hello",
    "isMessageFromUser": true,
    "isRead": false,
    "messageTime": "Thu Aug 03,2023,2:58 PM",
    "fromUserOnlineStatus": "Online",
    "toUserOnlineStatus": "Online",
    "createdDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "modifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "createdBy": null,
    "modifiedBy": null,
    "cancelled": false
}
```

**After Conversion:**

```
{
    "Id": 187,
    "FromUserId": 1,
    "FromUserFullName": "Super Admin",
    "ToUserId": 3,
    "ToUserFullName": "Super Admin",
    "Message": "Hello",
    "IsMessageFromUser": true,
    "IsRead": false,
    "MessageTime": "Thu Aug 03,2023,2:58 PM",
    "FromUserOnlineStatus": "Online",
    "ToUserOnlineStatus": "Online",
    "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "ModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "CreatedBy": null,
    "ModifiedBy": null,
    "Cancelled": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function I wrote which will convert all keys, including nested ones, into camelCase:

```js
function camelize(o) {
  if (typeof o !== 'object' || o === null) return o;

  const obj = {};
  for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(o)) {
    key = key.replace(/[\-_\s]+(.)?/g, (_, ch) => ch ? ch.toUpperCase() : '');
    key = key.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + key.substring(1);

    obj[key] = camelize(val);
  }
  return obj;
}

const obj = {
  "WhatIn_the-world_IsThis?": {
    "Not camelCase": "reallyBad"
  }
};

console.log("Before camelize:", obj);
console.log("After camelize:", camelize(obj));
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert object keys to camelCase with deep.

```
import _ from 'lodash';

export function objectKeysToCamelCase(entity) {
    if (!_.isObject(entity)) return entity;

    let result;

    result = _.mapKeys(entity, (value, key) => _.camelCase(key));
    result = _.mapValues(result, (value) => objectKeysToCamelCase(value));

    return result;
}
```