# Transform all keys in array from underscore to camel case in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

So, I need to transform all keys in array from underscore to camel space in js. That is what I need to do before send form to server. I'm using `Angular.js` and I want to represent it as a filter (but I think it's not rly important in this case). Anyway, here is a function I've created.

```
.filter('underscoreToCamelKeys', function () {
        return function (data) {

            var tmp = [];
            function keyReverse(array) {
                angular.forEach(array, function (value, key) {
                        tmp[value] = underscoreToCamelcase(key);
                });

                return tmp;
            }

            var new_obj = {};
            for (var prop in keyReverse(data)) {
                if(tmp.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    new_obj[tmp[prop]] = prop;
                }
            }
            return new_obj;
        };

        function underscoreToCamelcase (string) {
            return string.replace(/(\_\w)/g, function(m){
                return m[1].toUpperCase();
            });
        }
    })
```

Here I will try to explain how it works, because it looks terrible at first.

`underscoreToCamelcase` function just reverting any string in underscore to came case, except first character (like this `some_string => someString`)

So, as I said earlier, I should revert all keys to camel case, but as you understant we can't simply write

```
date[key] = underscoreToCamelcase(key)
```

so `keyReverse` function returns a reverted array, here is example

`some_key` => `value`

will be

`value` => `someKey`

and for the last I simply reverting keys and values back, to get this

`someKey` => `value`

But, as you already may understand, I got a problem, if in array exists the same values, those data will be dissapear

array

`some_key1` => `value`,
`some_key2` => `value`

returns as

`someKey2` => `value`

So how can I fix that? I have a suggestion to check if those value exists and if it is add some special substring, like this

`some_key1` => `value`,
`some_key2` => `value`

`value` => `someKey1`,
`zx99value` => `someKey2`

and after all parse it for zx99, but it I think I`m going crazy...
Maybe some one have a better solution in this case?

Important! Them main problem is not just to transform some string to camel  case, but do it with array keys!

Comment: one solution is to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/camelcase which does exactly what you want.

Comment: It is not, because the problem is to revert array keys to camel case, but not to camelize just string, I already created a function to camelize string `underscoreToCamelcase`

Comment: `var str = "under_score",
     rep = str.replace(/_([a-z])/,function(match, p1) { return p1.toUpperCase(); }); // <- underScore`

Comment: Guys, my underscore to camelcase function works perfect, that is named `underscoreToCamelcase`, the problem is to revert array keys

Comment: Why are you switching around the key/value pair in the first place?  Why not just replace the keys as you go?  e.g. extract the value and key, delete the current key, set the value under the transformed key

Comment: uh, you right! thanks! it was so close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.filter('underscoreToCamelKeys', function () {
        return function (data) {

            var tmp = {};
            angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                var tmpvalue = underscoreToCamelcase(key);
                tmp[tmpvalue] = value;
            });

            return tmp;
        };

        function underscoreToCamelcase (string) {
            return string.replace(/(\_\w)/g, function(m){
                return m[1].toUpperCase();
            });
        }
    })
```

thanks to ryanlutgen

Answer (score 5):

If you use an existing library to do the camelCase transform, you can then reduce an object like so

```
import {camelCase} from 'lodash/string'

const camelCaseKeys = (obj) =>
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((ccObj, field) => ({
    ...ccObj,
    [camelCase(field)]: obj[field]
  }), {})
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with nested json objects

Comment: `[camelCase(field)]: typeof obj === "object" ? camelCaseKeys(obj[field]) :  obj[field]`

Would do that

Comment: Your example for nested objects is great, but brakes the values. Here's working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50620653/3332734

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you could use the optional `replacer` parameter of the `JSON.stringify` method.

```
var result = JSON.stringify(myVal, function (key, value) {

  if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
    var replacement = {};
    for (var k in value) {
      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value, k)) {
        replacement[underscoreToCamelcase(k)] = value[k];
      }
    }
    return replacement;
  }

  return value;
});
```

Of course you'll end up with a string and have to call `JSON.parse` to get the object.