# TypeScript function that converts returned JSON Object Property keys to camelCase?

Tags: typescript

I need to convert returned JSON Object Properties to (lower first) camelCase.

And so I'm trying to make a TypeScript version of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50620653/1526396).

Here is my attempt so far:

```TypeScript
import { camelCase, isPlainObject } from 'lodash';

const camelizeKeys = ( // < -- 1st Error here
  obj: Record<string, unknown> | Record<string, unknown>[]
) => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.map((v: Record<string, unknown>) => camelizeKeys(v));
  } else if (isPlainObject(obj)) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(
      (result, key) => ({ // < -- 2nd Error here
        ...result,
        [camelCase(key)]: camelizeKeys(obj[key]),
      }),
      {}
    );
  }
  return obj;
};
```

But I am seeing this 1st error on `const camelizeKeys`:

> 'camelizeKeys' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not
> have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly
> in one of its return expressions.ts(7023)

And also seeing this 2nd error on first `reduce` argument:

> Function implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a
> return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one
> of its return expressions.ts(7024)

Comment: An interesting question, but a bit confusing to me! Can you please publish a working code sample and share the link here to assist you better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have expanded on the answer provided by @kelly to create this fully working solution.

It works for both objects and arrays that contain objects.

```TypeScript
import { camelCase, isPlainObject } from 'lodash';
const camelizeKeys = <
  T extends Record<string, unknown> | Record<string, unknown>[]
>(
  obj: T
): T => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return <T>obj.map((v) => camelizeKeys(v));
  } else if (isPlainObject(obj)) {
    return <T>Object.keys(obj).reduce(
      (result, key) => ({
        ...result,
        [camelCase(key)]: camelizeKeys(<T>obj[key]),
      }),
      {}
    );
  }
  return obj;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is recursive, you need to explicitly annotate the return type:

```
const camelizeKeys = <T extends Record<string, unknown> | Record<string, unknown>[]>(
  obj: T
): T => { ... }
```

Here I used a generic because if its an object, it returns an object. Same for an array.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this throws up new errors for the generic T. See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-duhftn?file=index.ts